# MVVM: Why the ViewModel is always recreated when Activity rotated

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-koin

My setup is: java Activity getting a ViewModel using Koin. All good with this, but when I rotate a phone, the ViewModel is always recreated. So how to avoid ViewModel recreation in the case? Thanks.

Activity:

```
private final FlowViewModel viewModel = get(FlowViewModel.class);
```

Koin:

```
val appModule = module {
     ...
     viewModel { FlowViewModel(get()) }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Koin, but something needs to call `ViewModelProviders(lifecycleOwner).get(FlowViewModel.class)` so that the ViewModel instance is retained across configuration changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're injecting the viewmodel as a regular object with `get()` and not as a viewmodel. It does not get any viewmodel special treatment.

To use koin-managed viewmodels in java, you can add the library `io.insert-koin:koin-android-compat` and access viewmodels in koin graph with `getViewModel()` rather than `get()`. See https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel#viewmodel-api---java-compat

Comment: Thanks, this works great: `ViewModelCompat.getViewModel(this, FlowViewModel.class)`